# Is there any api to get all words regarding a particular topic available in english grammar

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, wordnet

I am working on NLP with python and my next step is to gather huge-huge data regarding specific topics available in English grammar.

For example : all words that can define a "Department" say  "Accounts".

So can any tell me how I can gather such data (if possible, through any API).

Comment: Please do take some time to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NLTK wordnet is a great framework for these kind of problems. Here is a brief documentation:
http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html  This uses things objects like "synset" which gives you words with common meanings. There are also ways to get a numerical score for the similarities of two words. Lemmas will give you words with similar root meanings.

If you are looking for more of a find related words (ex: "spaghetti" --> "pasta", "ravioli", "Italy" database is probably better:
https://www.datamuse.com/api/

Comment: Thanx a lot.. I think I have got a direction.. with the help of the "datamuse" api I can collect those data.. but don't know how far...

Comment: What do you mean by don't know how far?